# Intuition ("resolving power") of $L^p$ norm or space

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I am now studying functional analysis, especially $L^p$ spaces and I'm wondering **what kind of property of functions the $L^p$ norms measure.**
I know that when $\Omega$ has a finite measure, there exists the relation, $L^q(\Omega)\subset L^p(\Omega)$ for $1 \leq p < q \leq \infty $. But in general, it seems that there is no such a simple relation, and I ask this question.
(If there would be such a relation, it would be safe to say "That is the resolving power of each $L^p$ norms.", but there is not....)

Anything will help, thanks!

Comment: One interesting relation is that $L^p \cap L^q \subset L^r \subset L^p + L^q$ for any $p \leq r \leq q$.

Comment: @Wang Thank you! I didn't know that; would you give me a reference of the relation? (and if you know why should be such relation intuitionally, it will be very helpful for me)

Comment: A reference can be found in Wiki. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_space#Relations_between_the_interpolation_methods

Comment: @YuxinWang thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume we are considering $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$. It may help to look at some examples: for instance, $f(x) := \inf\left\{1,\frac{1}{|x|}\right\}$ is not in $L^1$, but in $L^p$ for $p > 1$; in this sense, $L^p$ measures "how fast does a function decay". Consider $f(x) := \chi_{[-1,1]} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}$, then $f$ is in $L^p$ for $1 \leq p < 2$; in this case $L^p$ measures "how fast does a function blow up". In general, $p=1$ measures if a function is absolutely integrable. As $p$ increases, the integral $\int |f(x)|^p\, dx$ will, in a very vague sense, concentrate on the portion where $|f(x)|$ is large. In particular, $p = \infty$ corresponds to the $\sup$-norm, which measures the supremum of $|f(x)|$ on the entire domain.

One general (yet interesting) relation is that $L^p \cap L^q \subset L^r \subset L^p + L^q$ for any $p \leq r \leq q$. The first inclusion follows from interpolation between $L^p$ norms; the second inclusion is (roughly) because we can take the "smaller" and "larger" part of an $L^r$ function and argue that they are in the desired spaces.

Also $C_c^\infty$ is dense in any $L^p$ for all $1 \leq p < \infty$ (so often times proving properties of operators on $L^p$ reduces to proving them for $C_c^\infty$ functions). Hence the $L^p$ spaces all contain the same dense subset (for $p <\infty$).

Comment: Excuse me but $f(x) := \inf\{1, |x|\} $ seems not in $L^p,\, p > 1 $, it cannot be $p$-th powered integrable on $\mathbf{R}$ --- maybe you mean  $f(x) := \inf\left\{1, \frac{1}{|x|}\right\} $?

Comment: You are absolutely right! Sorry about that, I've got it corrected.

Comment: I think I got it a little; for example, comparing $f(x) := \frac{1}{|x|}$ and $g(x) := \frac{1}{|x|^2}$, $f(x)$ decays slower than $g(x)$ but also blow-up slower around $0$. These two properties are struggling each other and that makes the problem difficult, right?

Comment: That's right, though neither of these two functions are in any $L^p$ space because for any $\alpha$, positive or negative, the function $|x|^\alpha$ is not integrable either near $x = 0$ or near $x = \infty$ (or both, say for $\alpha = -1$). In other more complicated scenarios, we usually focus on one aspect at a time, namely, on the region when the function blows up near a singularity, or when the domain of integration is unbounded. Outside these two aspects, the functions is bounded on a bounded domain, so usually nothing very interesting would happen.

Comment: Thanks to you, I can get some intuition of the $L^p$ norms, thank you!